# Click on Text and Checkbox separately in CheckBoxPreference

Tags: android

I am creating a PreferenceActivity by using the PreferenceScreen xml. I wants to open a new preference screen when click on the label(title) of a CheckBoxPreference and when the user click on check box of this CheckBoxPreference then normal preference functionality will work.
So how can I do it?

**For Example:** Change a user profile(by click on radio buttons) and changing its properties(by clicking on label of this radio button) in android

Comment: You mean to say change pref should happen on same screen and clicking on title (lablel) should open a new activity??

Comment: yes, clicking on title open a new preference activity. I wants to use functionality something like setting the user profile in android.

Comment: Its easy, when you click on title create preference intent and launch it, where is the problem in it?. what exactly the problem you are facing?

Comment: So as you say above, Is it possible that android default CheckBoxPreference provide click on title and check box both?

Comment: I have understood your question like this, there will be a label and radio button, you need to click on radio button which leads to a setting page, and clicking on title takes you to another activity. now you need to explain in detail what you want to do?. else its tough to answer

Answer (score 1):

I think it's hard to do with a default preference. But you can try extending the original [`onBindView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#onBindView(android.view.View)) method, according to the documentation: `This is a good place to grab references to custom Views in the layout and set properties on them.` So, this is an example for `CheckBoxPreference` to be clickable on text.

```
public class MyCheckBoxPreference extends CheckBoxPreference {
    static final String TAG = "MyCheckBoxPreference";

    public MyCheckBoxPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public MyCheckBoxPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyCheckBoxPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindView(View v) {
        super.onBindView(v);
        ((ViewGroup) v).getChildAt(1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onClick " + getKey());
            }
        });
    }
}
```